# How set styleClass in specific cell with p:panelGrid

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I have this layout:

```
column1(border-left-only), column2(noborder), column3(noborder), column4(border-right-only)
```

then I set up column4 this way:

```
<p:column style="border-style: solid !important;
    border-left: none !important;
    border-bottom: none !important;
    border-top: none !important;
    border-right-color: #dddddd !important;">
```

Why is it that when I create the following CSS class and set up p:column, the class will not work?

```
    .panelgridInicialLogado-column4{
        border-style: solid !important;
        border-left: none !important;
        border-bottom: none !important;
        border-top: none !important;
        border-right-color: #dddddd !important;
    }


<p:column styleClass="panelgridInicialLogado-column4">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

My style

```
<style>
    .panelgridInicialLogado-column1{
        border-style: solid !important;
        border-bottom: none !important;
        border-top: none !important;
        border-right: none !important;
        border-left-color: red !important;
    }
    .panelgridInicialLogado-column2{
        border-left: none !important;
        border-bottom: none !important;
        border-top: none !important;
        border-right: none !important;
    }
    .panelgridInicialLogado-column3{
        border-left: none !important;
        border-bottom: none !important;
        border-top: none !important;
        border-right: none !important;
    }
    .panelgridInicialLogado-column4{
        border-style: solid !important;
        border-left: none !important;
        border-bottom: none !important;
        border-top: none !important;
        border-right-color: red !important;
    }
</style>
```

In panelGrid

```
<p:row>
    <p:column styleClass="panelgridInicialLogado-column1">Conf. Semifinals</p:column>
    <p:column styleClass="panelgridInicialLogado-column2">Conf. Finals</p:column>
    <p:column styleClass="panelgridInicialLogado-column3">NBA Finals</p:column>
    <p:column styleClass="panelgridInicialLogado-column4">Champion</p:column>
</p:row>
```

Comment: look this


Border-top and bottom : none.. then in my view, this border continue appearing.

 http://i.stack.imgur.com/LRUwf.png

 http://i.stack.imgur.com/gu4CE.png

Comment: Sorry, i removed border from table tr,td and solved.. thank you so much